# Number of categories slowing down the site

Tags: categories, taxonomy, performance

I had over 10K categories and posts on my WP site. Posts are created but don't have any content. I am hosting the site on mid-tier option for WP sites on Siteground.

Due to a large number of categories, my sites barely loads. Not sure if I am allowed to post a link to it.

According to Query Monitor, it takes 27 seconds to load the site. I am suspecting it is because of number of categories.

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance of the site? Maybe modify the way categories are pulled?

Comment: OK, so you’ve used Query Monitor. Great. What queries are using most of the time? How many queries are there?

Comment: In terms of time the biggest query is 0.0058 seconds with 65,000 rows.There are 35 queries all together.
Database Query Time is 0.0292
Page Generation Time is 28.2962

Does this mean that the categories may not be the root cause, this DB query time is so low

Comment: Well, as you’ve said - querying DB is not the problem. Generating the HTML is...

Comment: Are there tools to diagnose HTML generation?

Comment: Just take a look at that code and try to locate loops that may take a lot of time to execute...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the huge number of categories is responsible for slowing down your site. There might be other problems, like [render blocking resources](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-fix-render-blocking-javascript-and-css-of-your-wordpress-website/) and loops.

I recommend you to run your WordPress site through [Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/). It will help you find the exact reasons behind the slow speed. It will also recommend you the way of solving the specific issues.